# Razor Page Google Chrome Default DataPicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I am using the bootstrap4 gijgo datepicker and the below code works fine:

```
<div id="myDatePicker" class="form-group" style="display: none;">
     <label asp-for="Test.Date" class="control-label">Date</label>
     <input  id="datepicker" width="276"/>
     <span asp-validation-for="Test.Date" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The problem comes in when I add 'asp-for'. Googles default datepicker appears and breaks my datepicker.

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }


<div id="myDatePicker" class="form-group" style="display: none;">
     <label asp-for="Test.Date" class="control-label">Date</label>
     <input asp-for="Test.Date" id="datepicker" width="276"/>
     <span asp-validation-for="Test.Date" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        minDate: Date.now(),
        maxDate: function() {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setDate(date.getDate()+5);
            return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        }
    });
```

This works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing:

```
<input asp-for="Test.Date" id="datepicker" width="276"/>
```

to

```
<input type="text" asp-for="Test.Date" id="datepicker" width="276"/>
```